# Test database for username without authentication [Firebase/Swift 3]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My problem currently is that when a user wants to create an account on my app (using Firebase) the following error occurs:

> 2017-07-12 21:57:05.958 GeneralMessage[8525]  [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /users failed: permission_denied

I realise that the error occurs because the user attempts to read from the database without being signed in to an account (authenticated). The problem also being that the user will NEVER be authenticated at the time they are testing if a name is taken (before they make the account).

I know that you can edit the Realtime Database rules to allow unauthenticated users to access the database but I also read that this was a security hazard and should only be used during testing.

My idea was to temporarily authenticate the user when they click the 'Create Account' button but I am also unsure about how I would do this.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want unauthenticated users to be able to read part of your database, you'll need to modify your security rules to allow that. There is no way to do this temporarily for a specific app instance, since that would require each app instance to be identified - like a user.

I know two approaches:

1. Sign the user in with anonymous authentication first
2. Store the user names in an unprotected part of the tree

#### Sign the user in with anonymous authentication first

Alternatively you can initially sign the user in with anonymous authentication:

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

This only partially secures data access: since the user doesn't prove their identity, it's relatively easy for anyone to still get access to the data. That's why I recommend limiting the data they can access by...

#### Store the user names in an unprotected part of the tree

This approach is quite common: you want the usernames to be publicly readable, so you store that in a separate part of your database.

```
usernames
  "T. Dess": 8295647
  "Frank van Puffelen": 209103
```

And then with your security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    },
    "usernames": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

So with these rules:

- Anyone can read the usernames
- Any authenticated user can read the user profiles
- Each signed in user can only modify their own user profile